# Update new Django and Python 2.7.* with virtualenv on Dreamhost (with passenger)

Tags: python, django, passenger, dreamhost

Dreamhost is a great host for small project. And it's also Django friendly hosting. Everything good except python and Django version is a little bit out of date. Well it's a whole day of work to figure out how to update Python 2.7.3, Django 1.4 on dreamhost and I really want to share with whoever finding it

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I currently have private server, a shell account and a bit of luck. So here is what I do:

1. SSH to your host to upgrade python

   ```
    cd ~
    mkdir tmp
    cd tmp
    wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tgz
    tar zxvf Python-2.7.3.tgz
    cd Python-2.7.3
    ./configure --enable-shared --prefix=$HOME/Python27 --enable-unicode=ucs4
    make
    make install
   ```
2. Configure system to use our new Python. Open ~/.bashrc and add the following line

   ```
    export PATH="$HOME/Python27/bin:$PATH"
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/Python27/lib

    #save it and run
    source ~/.bashrc
   ```

   you can now check your python version with `which python`
3. Install `easy_install`, `pip`

   ```
   cd ~/tmp
   wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
   python ez_setup.py
   easy_install pip
   # Or even shorter
   wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
   python get-pip.py
   ```
4. Install `virtualenv`

   ```
    pip install virtualenv
    virtualenv $HOME/<site>/env
    #Switch to virtualenv
    source $HOME/<site>/env/bin/activate
   ```

   you can also add env path to `bashrc`

   ```
    export PATH="$HOME/<site>/env/bin/:$PATH"
    source ~/.bashrc
   ```
5. Install django and everything else

   ```
    pip install django
    pip install ....
    pip install ....
    pip install ....
   ```
6. Create project

   ```
    cd $HOME/<site>/
    python $HOME/<site>/env/bin/django-admin.py startproject project
   ```
7. Create `passenger_wsgi.py` in `HOME/<site>/` with following content

   ```
    import sys, os
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    sys.path.append(cwd)
    sys.path.append(cwd + '/project')  #You must add your project here or 500

    #Switch to new python
    #You may try to replace $HOME with your actual path
    if sys.version < "2.7.3": os.execl("$HOME/<site>/env/bin/python",
        "python2.7.3", *sys.argv)

    sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/<site>/env/bin')
    sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/<site>/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django')
    sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/<site>/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "project.settings"
    import django.core.handlers.wsgi
    application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
   ```

or this way

```
import sys, os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR))  #You must add your project here or 500

#Switch to new python
#You may try to replace $HOME with your actual path
PYTHON_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'env', 'bin', 'python')
if sys.executable != PYTHON_PATH:
    os.execl(PYTHON_PATH, "python2.7.12", *sys.argv)
```

If you are using django 1.7, replace the last two line with

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

8. Enjoy :D

---

New version of python on Dreamhost will no longer return `sys.executable` so you this is my version of passenger_wsgi

```
import sys, os

VIRTUAL_ENV_PYTHON = 'venv-python'  # Python > 2.7.6 dreamhost not return sys.executable
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def is_venv_python():
    if len(sys.argv) > 0:
        last_item = sys.argv[len(sys.argv)-1]
        if last_item == VIRTUAL_ENV_PYTHON:
            return True
    return False

sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR))  #You must add your project here or 500

#Switch to new python

PYTHON_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'env', 'bin', 'python')
if not is_venv_python():
    os.execl(PYTHON_PATH, "python2.7.12", *sys.argv + [VIRTUAL_ENV_PYTHON])

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'env', 'bin'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(
    BASE_DIR, 'env', 'lib', 'python2.7', 'site-packages'
))
```

Comment: It would be great if someone can write an automation script

Comment: we did not create any project directory inside env, did we?
sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/<site>/env/project')

getting An error occurred importing your passenger_wsgi.py even after /project from the that)

Comment: A slightly more general version of your python installation process is available in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/4699533)

Comment: And to complete the generalization exercise, here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/4699850) of the other half to install pip, venv, and a django app

Comment: For me I had an issue when it came to installing pip. When I ran `easy_install pip` it wanted to install it to the python 2.6 path. I ended up having to run `easy_install-2.7 pip`

Comment: You have to call `source your_enviroment_script` to change enviroment to your new path.... everytime you use shell

Comment: You should comment out instructions like "Open ~/.bashrc and add the following line" in step 2 so people don't run into issues when they copy and paste the code samples.

Comment: Also why not source .bashrc from .bash_profile so that it defaults to Python 2.7 upon login?

Comment: I needed to do `python ez_setup.py prefix=$HOME/Python27 -U setuptools`, followed by `easy_install-2.7 pip`

Comment: I get error: An error occurred importing your passenger_wsgi.py
what it could be? I changed every 'project' and <site> to my project and mysite.

Comment: "An error occurred importing your passenger_wsgi.py" normally this is caused by syntax error in your passenger.py file, or missing import statement. Where did you get the error, you can check apache log for more information

Comment: I tried 'python passenger_wsgi.py' in command prompt and it didnt turned any error. also my browser is very slow when i type address. and i get this error. (i dont get any record in error log, just in access log)

Comment: What happend when you try to start server using shell: python manage.py runserver ?

Comment: Amazing!! I struggle with the installations for the whole weekend. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently Dreamhost updated servers to Ubuntu 12.04, and i've got an error:

```
Import Error: <path-to-python>/_io.so undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_Decode
```

after compiling custom python and running "python ez_setup.py"

The solution was to compile python with --enable-unicode=ucs4 at step 1

```
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=$HOME/Python27 --enable-unicode=ucs4
```

Comment: *dont know* It also should be said, that current default python version on "happy hosting" == 2.7.3, but Django is still old, so I use your steps for creating virtualenv. It works fine! Thank you!