# Error on importing passenger_wsgi.py file

Tags: django, passenger, wsgi, dreamhost

I'm currently trying to set up a Django project using passenger wsgi. I followed the instructions laid out on this post:

[Update new Django and Python 2.7.* with virtualenv on Dreamhost (with passenger)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953695/update-django-1-4-and-python-2-7-3-with-virtualenv-on-dreamhost-with-passenger)

However, I'm receiving an error "An error occurred importing your passenger_wsgi.py"

I am able to successfully receive a hello word message if I put this as my passenger_wsgi.py:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])
    return ["Hello, world!"]
```

But for some reason if I use the following (outlined in the above post), I am unable to get past the error. I replace the word 'project' with my named project on the path.append and os.environ lines and  with subdomain.domain.com on the path.insert lines. Am I missing something? I am very new to this stuff and would appreciate any help I can get! Thanks.

Below is the current passenger_wsgi.py that receives the error on importing.

```
import sys, os
cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(cwd)
sys.path.append(cwd + '/project')

if sys.version < "2.7.3": os.execl("$HOME/<site>/env/bin/python",
"python2.7.3", *sys.argv)

sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/<site>/env/bin')
sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/<site>/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django')
sys.path.insert(0,'$HOME/<site>/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "project.settings"
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

---

**UPDATE** I was able to get a passenger wsgi that imports but now I'm getting a 500 error. Here is what I'm sitting at right now:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'project'))

sys.path.insert(0, 'home/<site>/env/bin')
sys.path.insert(0, 'home/<site>/env/lib/python2.7/site- packages/django')
sys.path.insert(0, 'home/<site>/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0, 'home/<site>/roommates')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "project.settings"
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Once again I'm stuck though. I can't seem to find why I'm getting this error. The current errors that are showing up in the error logs are as follows per attempt:

```
Premature end of script headers:
Premature end of script headers: internal_error.html
```

Comment: Did you replace all the other replaceables?

Comment: I replaced the append line, the version line, the environ line and the insert lines. The thing I"m not sure about is what the insert lines do and if I'm actually replacing them with the right thing...

Comment: @sailboatlie those insert lines make sure passenger can find library when you call `import ...`

Answer (score 0):

You should change this line:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'project'))
```

into

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd() + 'project'))
```

and make sure you change *project* with the name of your real project (or django app)