# PYTHON3.3 >> sybpydb.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_Decode

Tags: python, python-3.x, sap-ase

I am having trouble with this problem. I want to connect to sybase using python3.3. But error occurs when I enter the code:

```
import sybpydb

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/python/python31_64r/lib/sybpydb.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_Decode
```

I hope anyone can help me get rid of this....

Comment: The extension you have there works only with Python 3.1.

Answer (score 3):

The C extension you have there works only with Python 3.1.

Python 3.3 has an updated Unicode architecture, and the `PyUnicodeUCS2_Decode` function no longer exists in that version.

You'll need to find a version specifically for Python 3.3 or compile your own.

Because the C API has changed in this respect, it may be that the extension needs to be updated to work with Python 3.3; you'll need to contact the authors of the extension about this.

Comment: Thanks! Solved it by reverting to 3.1

Comment: Note that Python 3.1 is not the most performant or full-featured release, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recompile python with 
`./configure --enable-shared --prefix=$HOME/Python27 --enable-unicode=ucs4`

Follow [Update new Django and Python 2.7.* with virtualenv on Dreamhost (with passenger)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953695/update-new-django-and-python-2-7-with-virtualenv-on-dreamhost-with-passenger/26337429#26337429)