# Passenger WSGI error - Django Setup on Dreamhost

Tags: python, django, passenger, dreamhost, django-wsgi

I've just tried to setup and upload my Django project to Dreamhost.

I've followed the answer here : [Update new Django and Python 2.7.* with virtualenv on Dreamhost (with passenger)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953695/update-django-1-4-and-python-2-7-3-with-virtualenv-on-dreamhost-with-passenger)

Everything seemed to have worked fine up to the passenger_wsgi which gives me the error "An error occurred importing your passenger_wsgi.py" I've not had any experience with setting this kind of thing up before.

My current wsgi file

```
import sys, os
cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(cwd)
sys.path.append(cwd + '/projectname')

if sys.version < "2.7.5": os.excel("/home/<usr>/<domain.com>/env/bin/python",
    "python2.7.5", *sys.argv)

sys.path.insert(0, '/home/<usr>/<domain.com>/evn/bin')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/<usr>/<domain.com>/evn/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/<usr>/<domain.com>/evn/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "projectname.settings"
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

where

```
<usr>
```

is the Shell user, and

```
<domain.com>
```

is the folder for my domain-

I don't really know how to go about finding the source of the problem here, as I don't even know how I can debug this. I have tried changing some of the file directories in case I had something wrong but have had no luck.

I wonder if it could be something to do with Django being installed onto the Python virtualenv?

Comment: There is no problem with Django into a virtualenv.

Comment: I've been playing about and it's currently not giving the error, but it just hangs. Am I correct in starting the Django server by using the python virtualenv and running manage.py runserver whilst in Shell?

Comment: Yes you should be in the virtualenv since Django only exist there, FYI The 'runserver' command is just to have a lightweight development Web server.

Comment: I think I've sorted my issues will post back if the solution is worth while.

Comment: Please do post the solution :)